# Some Qt errors - How to solve?

Tags: c++, qt

I have the following `main.cpp` file:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include "ui_checkabder.h"
#include <QDialog>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
QApplication app(argc, argv);
Ui::CheckAbder ui;
QDialog *dialog = new QDialog;
ui.setupUi(dialog);
dialog->show();
return app.exec();
}
```

And, get the following errors when trying to run the program:

```
C:/Users/avbder/Desktop/abder/main.cpp:7: error: 'CheckAbder' is not a member of 'Ui'

C:/Users/avbder/Desktop/abder/main.cpp:7: error: expected ';' before 'ui'

C:/Users/avbder/Desktop/abder/main.cpp:7: error: expected ';' before 'ui'

C:/Users/avbder/Desktop/abder/main.cpp:9: error: 'ui' was not declared in this scope
```

The contents of `ui_checkabder.h` is as follows:

```
/********************************************************************************
** Form generated from reading UI file 'checkabder.ui'
**
** Created: Mon Apr 18 10:01:09 2011
**      by: Qt User Interface Compiler version 4.7.3
**
** WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost when recompiling UI file!
********************************************************************************/

#ifndef UI_CHECKABDER_H
#define UI_CHECKABDER_H

#include <QtCore/QVariant>
#include <QtGui/QAction>
#include <QtGui/QApplication>
#include <QtGui/QButtonGroup>
#include <QtGui/QHBoxLayout>
#include <QtGui/QHeaderView>
#include <QtGui/QLabel>
#include <QtGui/QLineEdit>
#include <QtGui/QPushButton>
#include <QtGui/QVBoxLayout>
#include <QtGui/QWidget>

QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE

class Ui_Form
{
public:
    QVBoxLayout *verticalLayout;
    QHBoxLayout *horizontalLayout;
    QLabel *label;
    QLineEdit *lineEdit;
    QHBoxLayout *horizontalLayout_2;
    QPushButton *okButton;
    QPushButton *cancelButton;

    void setupUi(QWidget *Form)
    {
        if (Form->objectName().isEmpty())
            Form->setObjectName(QString::fromUtf8("Form"));
        Form->resize(400, 300);
        verticalLayout = new QVBoxLayout(Form);
        verticalLayout->setObjectName(QString::fromUtf8("verticalLayout"));
        horizontalLayout = new QHBoxLayout();
        horizontalLayout->setObjectName(QString::fromUtf8("horizontalLayout"));
        label = new QLabel(Form);
        label->setObjectName(QString::fromUtf8("label"));
        QFont font;
        font.setFamily(QString::fromUtf8("Comic Sans MS"));
        font.setPointSize(16);
        label->setFont(font);

        horizontalLayout->addWidget(label);

        lineEdit = new QLineEdit(Form);
        lineEdit->setObjectName(QString::fromUtf8("lineEdit"));

        horizontalLayout->addWidget(lineEdit);


        verticalLayout->addLayout(horizontalLayout);

        horizontalLayout_2 = new QHBoxLayout();
        horizontalLayout_2->setObjectName(QString::fromUtf8("horizontalLayout_2"));
        okButton = new QPushButton(Form);
        okButton->setObjectName(QString::fromUtf8("okButton"));
        okButton->setEnabled(false);
        QFont font1;
        font1.setFamily(QString::fromUtf8("Comic Sans MS"));
        font1.setBold(true);
        font1.setWeight(75);
        okButton->setFont(font1);

        horizontalLayout_2->addWidget(okButton);

        cancelButton = new QPushButton(Form);
        cancelButton->setObjectName(QString::fromUtf8("cancelButton"));
        cancelButton->setFont(font1);

        horizontalLayout_2->addWidget(cancelButton);


        verticalLayout->addLayout(horizontalLayout_2);


        retranslateUi(Form);

        QMetaObject::connectSlotsByName(Form);
    } // setupUi

    void retranslateUi(QWidget *Form)
    {
        Form->setWindowTitle(QApplication::translate("Form", "Form", 0, QApplication::UnicodeUTF8));
        label->setText(QApplication::translate("Form", "Name", 0, QApplication::UnicodeUTF8));
        okButton->setText(QApplication::translate("Form", "OK", 0, QApplication::UnicodeUTF8));
        cancelButton->setText(QApplication::translate("Form", "CANCEL", 0, QApplication::UnicodeUTF8));
    } // retranslateUi

};

namespace Ui {
    class Form: public Ui_Form {};
} // namespace Ui

QT_END_NAMESPACE

#endif // UI_CHECKABDER_H
```

Any ideas on how to solve those problems?

Thanks.

Comment: What does ui_checkabder.h file contain?

Comment: @Kamil Klimek. Thanks for your reply. I have included `ui_checkabder.h` in my orginal post

Answer (score 1):

Your class name is `Ui_Form` and `Ui::Form` and not `CheckAbder`. You should rename it in Designer.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Since I'm new to `Qt`, can you explain it further?

Comment: just edit checkabder.ui file with Qt Designer, in object tree select root element (first one), and change it's object name to CheckAbder

Answer (score 1):

You need to understand uic a little bit. File name has nothing to do with generated Ui namespaces content. Your widget in .ui file is named "Form" not CheckAbder. You can solve your problem in two ways:

1. Start using Ui::Form in your .cpp file
2. Rename Form to CheckAbder in you .ui file

Also make sure, your .ui file is added to project, so it will automaticly generate new ui_*.h file after you change .ui

Answer (score -4):

```
namespace Ui {
    class Form: public Ui_Form {};
} // namespace Ui
```

should be

```
namespace Ui {
    class CheckAbder: public Ui_Form {};
} // namespace Ui
```

Comment: Ofcourse, it should be. But remember that ui_checkabder.h is generated header, that will change whenever changes in .ui file are made

Comment: Well in that case you use Ui::Form instead of Ui::CheckAbder. Pfff

Comment: You need to change the object name of the root object in your .ui file to the class name that you desire.  The generated header file will then use the name you want, instead of the default name "form"